# Subset is closed IFF limit of every sequence $x_{n}$ results in x in the subset

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

> Proposition:
>
> A subset $U \subseteq  X$ is closed IFF for every sequence $x_{n}\rightarrow x$ with $x_{n} \in U$
> for all n we also have $x \in U$.

The way in which the proof started out puzzles me. I've never seen proof like this before so either there is a mistake in the proposition from which my notes came from or I am misunderstanding the proposition.

Proof: First suppose U is closed and $x_{n}\rightarrow x$ with $x_{n} \in U$.

Right off the bat, the proof baffles me. From my knowledge, it is perfectly fine to assume first that $U \subseteq X$ is closed and then show that it leads to the fact that for every sequence $x_{n}\rightarrow x$ with $x_{n} \in U$
for all n, we also have $x \in U$.
But what the proof seems to be now is that the author assumes both the antecedent and the consequences.

A bit of clarification would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: He never assumed that $x \in U$, he is proving this.

Comment: It would be extremely helpful if you could write out the proof or at least write out part of the proof which confuses you.

Comment: My understanding of the proposition is this:
A subset U of X is closed ONLY IF for every sequence $x_{n} \rightarrow x$ with $x_{n} \in U$ for all n then $x \in U$.

In short, the "....every sequence $x_{n} \rightarrow x$ with $x_{n} \in U$ for all n then $x \in U$ is what the author ought to be proving ."-at least to my understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Theorem**:
$\forall U\subseteq X,~\left(U\text{ is closed }\displaystyle\Longleftrightarrow\forall \{x_n\}\subseteq U,~(\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x\Rightarrow x\in U)\right)$

**Proof:**

**Step 1:** Since this is a universal quantification. The regular way to prove such universal quantification is first let (any) $U\subseteq X$, and show:

> $U$ is closed$\displaystyle\Longleftrightarrow\forall \{x_n\}\subseteq U,~(\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x\Rightarrow x\in U)$

(if this holds, then we know "$\forall U\subseteq X,\cdots$(the yellow part)" holds.)

Anyway, we next want to show (WTS) the yellow part.

**Step 2:** We first prove "$\Rightarrow$" holds(it's exactly what you ask, so the other direction is omitted):

Suppose $U$ is closed, WTS

> $\displaystyle\forall \{x_n\}\subseteq U,~(\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x\Rightarrow x\in U)$

**Step 3:** Next, the universal quantification again! Let $\{x_n\}\subseteq U$, WTS

> $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x\Rightarrow x\in U$

**Step 4:** Next again, we suppose $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x$, and WTS

> $x\in U$

Final step:
if you have shown  $x\in U$, then it's all done.

Comment: feel free to ask me if there's somewhere you don't understand

Comment: It is now clear.